# Declaration of an array in disassembled code

Tags: c, assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, 32-bit

I try disassemble ropasaurusrex. this is CTF's Question.you can download Executable file from follow link. I use Hopper for disassemble.
[here](http://shell-storm.org/repo/CTF/PlaidCTF-2013/Pwnable/ropasaurusrex-200/ropasaurusrex-85a84f36f81e11f720b1cf5ea0d1fb0d5a603c0d)

[image]

The picture above is main routine of this program.

Please look at red line on the above picture.

It seems that declaration of the array is here.

`lea   eax, dword [ss:ebp+var_88]  =====>  char buffer[128];`

Why? I can not understand 128bytes?

Comment: The allocation happens just a bit before, in `mov esp, 0x98`. Besides allocating `0x80` for the `buffer`, it also allocates `0x18` for other variables in that scope. The `lea` instruction is just to determine the *address* of `buffer` on the stack.

Comment: Thak you comment! i see.

Comment: Thak you comment! i see. but, I still don't understand.sorry. why allocating 0x80 for the buffer? why do you find 0x80. Thank you!

Comment: @stackosiete: `0x80` is the hexadecimal representation of `128`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, there is no direct correspondence between individual assembly instructions and C constructs. A single instruction may be just a single "brick" from a larger construct. If optimisations are turned on, tracing things this way becomes even harder.

Considering the first routine, here is an instruction-by-instruction walkthrough:

- `push ebp` saves the old "stack base pointer" on the stack, so that it can restored after leaving the function and the caller can be confident that it hasn't changed;
- `mov ebp, esp` loads the value of the "base pointer" with the current value of the "stack pointer". Any further references to variables within the stack frame of that function can be made relative to this newly assigned base pointer;
- `sub esp, 0x98` subtracts the value `152` from the stack pointer. This effectively "allocates" space on the stack. Any variables with automatic storage can be now accommodated between the addresses pointed to by `ebp` and `esp`. This probably includes your `buffer` array.
- `mov dword[ss:esp + 8], 0x100` puts the value `256` at the address pointed to by `esp + 8`. That might correspond to an assignment to an automatic variable/array.
- `lea eax, dword[ss:ebp + var_88]` computes an address that is the result of the base pointer plus some constant offset, and stores it into `eax`. This probably corresponds to a pointer to the beginning of the automatic array.
- `eax` is then moved to the stack as an argument to the following call to `j_read`. `0` is also passed as the first argument. The function is then called, the leave instruction restores the old base pointer and the control is returned to the caller via the `ret` instruction.